# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. by Routing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am a beginner with React and trying to do some Routing.

I'm trying to implement Route in React to redirect to another page, but everytime i insert , it shows error: Invalid hook call.

Here's the code from App.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import Nav from './Nav';
    import EKGSim from './EKGSim';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
    
    function App() {
      return(
        <Router>
        <div className='App'>
          <Nav />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/ekgsim" element={<EKGSim/>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        </Router>
      )
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?
I've been trying for hours searching for the solution but came up to nothing.
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Code for the Nav.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Nav(){
    return(
        <nav>
            <h3>Home</h3>
            <ul className='nav-links'>
                <li>Was Ist EKG?</li>
                <li>EKG Component</li>
                <li>EKG Simulator</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Nav;
```

and the EKGSim.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function EKGSim(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>EKG Simulator

            </h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default EKGSim;
```

Comment: Pretty sure your `Route` elements need to be children of (depending on the version of React Router) either `Routes` or `BrowserRouter`, yours are inside your div with the App CSS class.

Comment: If you have fixed the `App` component like I said, rest looks fine to me. Where are you using your `App` component?

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for your answer, but sorry i just don't understand what you meant. What does it mean that the Route is inside my div with the App.css?

Comment: @VishnuSajeev Yes, i've once again edited the question with your code's snippets. 
All of these components are in the src.

Comment: Components, like HTML tags, exist in a nested, hierarchical structure. I'm saying I'm pretty sure the `Route` JSX tag needs to be a *direct* child of the `Routes` JSX tag, not nested inside another tag like your `div`. I'm not 100% sure though (which is why this is a comment, not an answer), it's been a couple of years since I worked with React Router.

Comment: @JaredSmith Hmm, i don't know if that's a problem is, but it is just weird because even with the code that i directly copy and paste from reactrouter's website, it still showing this error.

Comment: @ReynaldJhonson one other thing that can cause an invalid hook call even if you don't is having two versions of React itself on the same page. Check that. Other than that, I don't know what to tell you other than to start from scratch with a new project and a clean install of react, react-dom, and react-router and start with hello world (make sure that runs) and iterate from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I just run this command `npm install --save react-router-dom`
and it run perfectly!

I think the problem was that there was no react-router-dom in my package.json.

Thanks for everyone's answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Route` inside `Routes` try this

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/ekgsim" element={<EKGSim/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey Vishnu! Appreciate your comment. I've tried your code but unfortunately the problem still there. 

×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: Can you paste the code for your `Nav` and `EKGSim` component?

Comment: Sure, i will post in as an answer.

Comment: @stormshadow no, please *edit it into the question*. Answers are for, well, answers.

Comment: @JaredSmith Ah sure! Sorry! I have deleted the answer and edited the question :D

Comment: Pretty sure Route elements need to be children of (depending on the version of React Router) either Routes or BrowserRouter, you still have them in the OP's div.